# Is it true that if $V,W\subset \mathbb R^n$ are diffeomorphic, then the assumption that $V$ is open implies that $W$ is open too?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is it true that if $V,W\subset \mathbb R^n$ are diffeomorphic, then the assumption that $V$ is open implies that $W$ is open too? If this is true, then how to prove it?

Here is what I've considered so far: $\forall p\in V$, we wish to find an open neighborhood $O$ of $f(p)$, such that $O\subset  W$ and now I'm stuck right here.

Comment: What are $V$ and $W$? If they are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then what does it mean for them to be diffeomorphic? I think you need to rectify your notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: What does the hypothesis that $V$ is open say about the point $p$?